# Clojure: List Substitution Function

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a function which, given a collection and a sequence of replacements, replaces any lists in the collection with the next replacement in the order they appear.

For example:

```
(substitute '(+ 1 (* 2 3) 4 (* 5 6) [:a :b]) => (+ 1 :a 4 :b)
(substitute '[1 (2 3 4) (5 6 7)] [:x :y :z]) => [1 :x :y]
(substitute '[(1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)] [:x :y]) => [:x :y (7 8 9)]
```

Currently I have this:

```
(defn substitute
  [form syms]
  (if (seq form) 
    (lazy-seq
     (if (and (not-empty syms) (list? (first form)))
       (cons 
        (first syms)
        (substitute (rest form) (rest syms)))
       (cons 
        (first form)
        (substitute (rest form) syms))))))
```

However I have two problems. First, I want the output to be the same type as `form`. I tried doing `(into (empty form) (substitute form syms))` but this causes the output to be reversed when `form` is a list. Second, I am struggling to find a way to make this work on maps (I want to check for a list in both the key and value of each entry).

Any tips or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not directly answering your question, sorry, but ... if I was faced with this kind of problem, my first instinct would be to reach for specter. https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter

Comment: You can try this: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html#clojure.walk/postwalk-replace

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `clojure.walk/prewalk` to traverse the `form` in order *(pre-order)* and using an atom to track what `syms` remain for substitution:

```
(defn substitute [form syms]
  (let [syms' (atom syms)
        depth (atom 0)]
    (walk/prewalk
      (fn [v]
        (cond
          (= 1 (swap! depth inc)) v ;; don't examine the input form itself
          (list? v) (if-let [sym (first @syms')]
                      (do (swap! syms' rest)
                          sym)
                      v)
          :else v))
      form)))
```

The `depth` atom is to ensure we don't act on the *first* value which will be `form` itself, and if it were a list we wouldn't want to substitute the whole thing. At first I just checked `(not= form v)` but thought that could backfire if your `form` contains nested forms identical/equal to the outer `form`. *I suspect there's a better way to accomplish this!*

`prewalk` (and `postwalk`) also relieve you of having to worry about the *type* of collection you're walking i.e. lists will come out in the correct order.

```
(substitute '(+ 1 (* 2 3) 4 (* 5 6)) [:a :b])
=> (+ 1 :a 4 :b)
(substitute '[1 (2 3 4) (5 6 7)] [:x :y :z])
=> [1 :x :y]
(substitute '[(1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)] [:x :y])
=> [:x :y (7 8 9)]
```

Using `prewalk` also allows this to work on maps w/o additional effort:

```
(substitute {:foo '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) "hey"} [:a :b])
=> {:foo :a, :b "hey"}
```

You can also use `prewalk-demo` to illustrate how the form is traversed:

```
(walk/prewalk-demo {:foo '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) "hey"})
Walked: {:foo (1 2 3), (4 5 6) "hey"}
Walked: [:foo (1 2 3)]
Walked: :foo
Walked: (1 2 3)
Walked: 1
Walked: 2
Walked: 3
Walked: [(4 5 6) "hey"]
Walked: (4 5 6)
Walked: 4
Walked: 5
Walked: 6
Walked: "hey"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied. I think I may have cracked it now.

```
(defn map-to-vec
  [map]
  (reduce-kv (fn [vec k v] (into vec [k v])) [] map))

(defn substitute-seq
  [form syms]
  (if (seq form) 
    (lazy-seq
     (if (and (not-empty syms) (list? (first form)))
       (cons 
        (first syms)
        (substitute-seq (rest form) (rest syms)))
       (cons 
        (first form)
        (substitute-seq (rest form) syms))))))

(defn substitute
  [form syms]
  (cond
   (list? form) (apply list (sub-syms-seq form syms))
   (map? form) 
   (reduce
    (fn [m [k v]] (conj m [k v]))
    (empty form) 
    (partition 2 (sub-syms-seq (map-to-vec form) syms)))
   (coll? form) (into (empty form) (sub-syms-seq form syms))))
```

I wrote a function `map-to-vec` which converts a map into a vector, such that `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}` becomes `[:a 1 :b 2 :c 3]` and added a helper function which ensures that the type of the output is the same as the input and, in the case of the input being a map, performs the main function (now called `substitute-seq`) on the `map-to-vec`ed map and then converts it back into a map again.

I'm sure there's still a better and more efficient way to do this but I suppose this works.

Comment: Check out the answer using `prewalk` above too as suggested by @leetwinski.